# Get clicked element using jQuery on event?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, click, jquery-events

I'm using the following code to detect when a dynamically generated button is clicked.

```
$(document).on("click",".appDetails", function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

Normally, if you just did `$('.appDetails').click()` you could use `$(this)` to get the element that was clicked on.  How would I accomplish this with the above code?

For instance:

```
$(document).on("click",".appDetails", function () {
    var clickedBtnID = ??????
    alert('you clicked on button #' + clickedBtnID);
});
```

Answer (score 166, accepted):

As simple as it can be

Use `$(this)` here too

```
$(document).on("click",".appDetails", function () {
   var clickedBtnID = $(this).attr('id'); // or var clickedBtnID = this.id
   alert('you clicked on button #' + clickedBtnID);
});
```

Comment: Looks like I'm dealing with a caching issue from the server.  Sorry.

Comment: A warning to those using ES6. Arrow functions do not set 'this' so this will be the parent. So, basically don't use an arrow function here.

Comment: @thomas-peter I say you turn that into an answer

Comment: @thomas-peter Saved me more dozens of minutes of frustration, thank you.

Comment: @thomas-peter you just saved me! i was trying to figure out why it wasn't woking for like 30 minutes... Thank you!

Comment: @thomas-peter Funny how trivial things can make you almost smash your PC. Saved me a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 69):

You are missing the event parameter on your function.

```
$(document).on("click",".appDetails", function (event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
});
```

Comment: This was perfect for me. It gives the element that was clicked - $(this) only gave the element that had the event attached.

Answer (score 50):

The conventional way of handling this doesn't play well with ES6. You can do this instead:

```
$('.delete').on('click', event => {
  const clickedElement = $(event.target);

  this.delete(clickedElement.data('id'));
});
```

Note that the event target will be the clicked element, which may not be the element you want (it could be a child that received the event). To get the actual element:

```
$('.delete').on('click', event => {
  const clickedElement = $(event.target);
  const targetElement = clickedElement.closest('.delete');

  this.delete(targetElement.data('id'));
});
```

Comment: You should use `event.currentTarget` to get the element the event is bound to. `event.target` is indeed the element that triggered the event. Your code `clickedElement.closest('.delete');` could fail if you have multiple nested elements with this class.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can do that

> > The first method is by using the javascript target

```
$(document).on("click",".appDetails", function (event) {
    var clickebtn = target.event.id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".masonry__img").click((e) => {
      console.log(e.currentTarget.currentSrc);
});
```

This will add an onClick handler to each image with the class masonry__img.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to pass the data attribute to your HTML tag.

Example:

```
<div data-id='tagid' class="clickElem"></div>

<script>
$(document).on("click",".appDetails", function () {
   var clickedBtnID = $(this).attr('data');
   alert('you clicked on button #' + clickedBtnID);
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is .appDetails here?