# Select only specific li clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to select the specific `li` clicked using jQuery in my project. When I click on one `li`, it selects all the `li's`. This is my fiddle. I am just a beginner. I have tried using parent(), but it is not working.
[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/timiosaze/68j9tnbk/6/)

This is my HTML:

```js
var clicks = 0;
$("li").on("click", function () {
  clicks++;
  $('.top-right').html(clicks);
});
```

```css
.list li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.list {
  margin: 5px;
}

.list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 2px;
}

.list li a:hover,
.list li a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Exam</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">NAME
          <span class="line"></span> AWONUSI OLAJIDE</a>
        <span class="top-right"></span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">NAME
          <span class="line"></span> ADEGBULUGBE TIMILEHIN</a>
        <span class="top-right"></span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">NAME
          <span class="line"></span> OLUOLU ADEDEJI</a>
        <span class="top-right">9999</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">NAME
          <span class="line"></span> OYAJE JOSHUA</a>
        <span class="top-right">9999</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">NAME
          <span class="line"></span> ALABI OJO ADE</a>
        <span class="top-right">9999</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">NAME
          <span class="line"></span> AKILO AWANI</a>
        <span class="top-right">9999</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">NAME
          <span class="line"></span> AYUBA DEJIMARK</a>
        <span class="top-right">9999</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [jQuery Event Basics | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get clicked element using jQuery on event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091823/get-clicked-element-using-jquery-on-event)

Comment: Not an exact dupe as the OP is trying to get something inside of the clicked element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.find()` to get the element inside the clicked element. Also the value you need to display is one more than the value already present inside it.

```
$("li").on("click", function() {
  $(this).find('.top-right').html(function(){
    return +$(this).html() + 1
  });
});
```

```js
$("li").on("click", function() {
  $(this).find('.top-right').html(function(){
    return +$(this).html() + 1
  });
});
```

```css
.list li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.list {
  margin: 5px;
}

.list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 2px;
}

.list li a:hover,
.list li a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Exam</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">NAME   <span class="line"></span> AWONUSI OLAJIDE</a><span class="top-right"></span></li>
      <li><a href="#">NAME   <span class="line"></span> ADEGBULUGBE TIMILEHIN</a><span class="top-right"></span></li>
      <li><a href="#">NAME   <span class="line"></span> OLUOLU ADEDEJI</a><span class="top-right">9999</span></li>
      <li><a href="#">NAME   <span class="line"></span> OYAJE JOSHUA</a><span class="top-right">9999</span></li>
      <li><a href="#">NAME   <span class="line"></span> ALABI OJO ADE</a><span class="top-right">9999</span></li>
      <li><a href="#">NAME   <span class="line"></span> AKILO AWANI</a><span class="top-right">9999</span></li>
      <li><a href="#">NAME   <span class="line"></span> AYUBA DEJIMARK</a><span class="top-right">9999</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```