# jQuery is not catching which element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Under my app i wonder which element is catching my click ,

I ve tried to to this test :

```
$(document).on('click', event => {
 const clickedElement = $(event.target);
 console.log(clickedElement);
});
```

When clicking under some elements its seems that jquery is not seeing the click ,

***nothing is printed in console***

How may is force this actions ?

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091823/get-clicked-element-using-jquery-on-event

Comment: `$('document')` needs to be `$(document)`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it is .. still not ctaching the click

Comment: With quotes removed, It has to work. If still not, wrap that code with `$(document).ready(function(){` and `});`

Comment: @firasKoubaa are you sure? It works fine here now you've corrected the selector: http://jsfiddle.net/52mq0gkj/

Comment: Code seams to be correct. Is jQuery loaded? Or are there some console errors?

Comment: likely the document or jquery hasn't loaded at the time of binding.tying wrapping it up with document ready

Comment: @digital-pollution if `$(document).on()` doesn't work "because it's not loaded yet", how would `$(document).ready` work? :P  The document definitely exists for both of those statements.

Comment: so you're saying it's just specific elements that don't get registered? Is it paert of a bigger application with other factors? We might need a working example for helping on that. By all means your code is correct and if wrapping in doc ready has no effect then it'll be some other factor not demonstrated in the code sample.