# Get clicked children element text with the on JQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw some questions who were similar to mine and even one that is [pretty much identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091823/get-clicked-element-using-jquery-on-event)
And the answer to that question was to use `$(this)` for some reason when I use this it executes the `$(this)` on the `document`.

```
var $dropDownItems = $('.notifi-drop').children();
$(document).on('click', $dropDownItems, function(event){
```

this is the code I am trying to execute. If I do a normal `.click()` event it works fine and I can use `this` to get  the corrent element. e.g

```
$($dropDownItems).click('click', function(event){
```

I tried the following (with the `on` event) but all of them were `undefined`

```
console.log($(this).attr('id'))
console.log($(event.target.text))
console.log($(this).text())
```

Just a note: If you didn't see, `$dropDownItems` is the children of a specific element. I guess that this is the problem in here.

The class and the children of the class:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu notifi-drop dropdown-menu-right">
                                {% for i in notifications %}
                                    <a class="dropdown-item friend-name-{{username}}">{{i}}</a>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger friend-rejected">Reject</button>
                                    <a>⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀</a>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success friend-accepted">Accept</button>
                                    <hr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
```

To clarify even more, I want to detect which child was clicked on and get the child's text.(what I am doing with the click even and `this`).

FYI: The reason I want to use the `on` event is because I am appending data and the click event can't handle it.

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.notifi-drop > *', function(event){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use event delegation, you should be using a selector, not a jQuery object.

So in your case you want to use `> *` to match the children of the element.

```
$(document).on('click', '.notifi-drop > *', function(event){
```

Comment: There is a minor problem now, when the data is appended and I am trying to get the index of the current child, it prints `-1` insted of the actual location (in my case it should print `2`). If I refresh the page it works fine, but for some reason when I append the data it's always `-1`. What do you think the problem is and how do you suggest in order to fix it?