# Jquery on(click) Each time you click, the information is taken from the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Each time you click, the data is taken from the first element

for example, i have couple links with parameters

```js
$(document).on('click', '.sitesubpay', function() {
  var siteid = $('.sitesubpay').data('siteid');
  var domaani = $('.sitesubpay').data('domain');
  $('.getmymodal').click();
  $("#domain").val(domaani);
  $("#myModalLabel").text(' for ' + domaani);
  console.log(siteid);
  console.log(domaani);
  var siteid = '';
  var domaani = '';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="sitesubpay" data-siteid="2121" data-domain="domain1.com"><span class="label label-warning">pending payment </span></a>
<a class="sitesubpay" data-siteid="2122" data-domain="domain2.com"><span class="label label-warning">pending payment </span></a>
<a class="sitesubpay" data-siteid="2123" data-domain="domain3.com"><span class="label label-warning">pending payment </span></a>
```

but each click on any element, returns the data of only the first
in the console.log

```
2121
domain1.com
```

Comment: Inside the function, use `$(this)` instead. `$('.sitesubpay')` will select all three of them again, and either use the first or give unexpected results.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+jquery+get+clicked+element) of [Get clicked element using jQuery on event?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16091823/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write this

```js
$(document).on('click', '.sitesubpay', function() {
  var siteid = $(this).data('siteid');
  var domaani = $(this).data('domain');
  $('.getmymodal').click();
  $("#domain").val(domaani);
  $("#myModalLabel").text(' for ' + domaani);
  console.log(siteid);
  console.log(domaani);
  var siteid = '';
  var domaani = '';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="sitesubpay" data-siteid="2121" data-domain="domain1.com"><span class="label label-warning">pending payment </span></a>
<a class="sitesubpay" data-siteid="2122" data-domain="domain2.com"><span class="label label-warning">pending payment </span></a>
<a class="sitesubpay" data-siteid="2123" data-domain="domain3.com"><span class="label label-warning">pending payment </span></a>
```